# C#: generic math functions (Min, Max etc.)

Tags: c#, math

I was thinking about writing generic functions for basic Math operations such as Min, Max etc.
But i i dont know how to compare two generic types :

```
public T Max<T>(T v1, T v2) where T: struct
{
   return (v1 > v2 ? v1 : v2);
}
```

How about that?

Thank you.

Comment: ps. Why limit Max to struct's?  It can be equally useful for classes, eg. strings.

Comment: Generally for anything that implements `IComparable`.

Comment: You are right, i did not know about IComparable interface. TY.

Comment: Note: you can do this for anything that involves comparisons because of IComparable but other maths functions may be impossible as there is no INumeric interface or equivalent

Comment: @jk - not impossible, just tricky; see the MiscUtil link in Luke's answer for code that supports the **operators** (rather than `IComparable[<T>]`).

Comment: how about `new[] {v1, v2}.Max()`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you only want to create comparison functions then you could use the [default comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azhsac5f.aspx) for the type `T`. For example:

```
public static T Max<T>(T x, T y)
{
    return (Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(x, y) > 0) ? x : y;
}
```

If `T` implements [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) then that comparer will be used; if `T` doesn't implement `IComparable<T>` but does implement [`IComparable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) then that comparer will be used; if `T` doesn't implement either `IComparable<T>` or `IComparable` then a runtime exception will be thrown.

If you want/need to do more than just compare the items then you could have a look at the [generic operators implementation in MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html) and the [related article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/genericoperators.html).

Comment: This is very elegant and generic solution. I like it too.

Comment: This is the right answer, IMO. As an aside, a common alternative pattern is to have two overloads; one passes `Comparer<T>.Default` to the second, which accepts `IComparer<T>` (for the cases when you want to customise it). But for the simple case, this is the way to go.

Comment: I disagree, se my post below

Comment: This is indeed the best solution. There is negligible runtime costs associated with it (and it's paid only the very first time a default comparer is created for a type). The Default.Comparer is also smarter and will handle corner cases better than using IComparable or IComparable<T>. Nice solution. It's indeed almost exactly the way I do it. I just use >= 0 so that the first "operand" is returned in case they are equal in the sort order...

Comment: If add constraint `T : IComparable<T>`, then the code can be simplified to `return (x.CompareTo(y) > 0) ...`. Easier to read. And no run-time evaluation or exception risk, since you have restricted T to types that can be compared.

Answer (score 27):

You probably want to [constrain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28VS.80%29.aspx) the generic types to implement [`IComparable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx):

```
public T Max<T>(T v1, T v2) where T: struct, IComparable<T>
```

and then use the [`CompareTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto.aspx) method:

```
{
    return (v1.CompareTo(v2) > 0 ? v1 : v2);
}
```

Comment: @Feryt:Note that there's no need to constrain it to `struct`s.

Comment: Well, the `struct` avoids the `null` problem, but IMO this is the wrong answer; Luke has the right of it.

Answer (score 5):

Let me disagree.
The @LukeH's implementation **is not Generic**.

I will explain why it is not Generic:

`Comparer<T>.Default` involves inspecting T at run-time to determine if it implements `IComparable<T>`, `IComparable` or neither.
Although this behavior is not well documented in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azhsac5f.aspx, we can deduct it because `Comparer<T>.Default` throws an exception when T does not implement neither. If the inspection was done at compilation-time there would be no need for an exception (runtime), with an compile-time error would suffice.

Then, as `Comparer<T>.Default` uses Reflection, this means a high cost on Run-Time, then...., **It is NOT Generic**... Why?

Because **Generic Programming** means: *A single algorithm (Generic) can cover many implementations (for many types) maintaining efficiency of hand-written versions.*

Take an example. The handwritten version for integers would be:

```
public static int Max( int x, int y)
{
    return (x.CompareTo(y) > 0) ? x : y;
}
```

It is very simple, involving only a comparison (or maybe more, depending on how Int32.CompareTo() is implemented).
If we use the @LukeH's implementation, we are adding Reflection to something that is very simple.

In short:

1. Always prefer Compilation-time errors to Run-Time Exceptions ( this is not Javascript, Ruby,... :-) )
2. This implementation is less efficient compared to the handwritten version (for any type)

On the other hand.
**What do you think Max should return when x and y are equivalents?**

I'm starting to analyze Real-Generic implementations....

The ideal implementation would be something like...

```
    public static T Max<T>(T x, T y, Func<T, T, int> cmp)
    {
        return (cmp(x, y) > 0) ? x : y;
    }

    //Pseudo-code ( note the 'or' next to 'where' )
    public static T Max<T>(T x, T y) where T: IComparable<T> or IComparable
    {
        return Max(x, y, (a, b) => { return a.CompareTo(b); });
    }
```

This is not possible in C#, the next try is could be...

```
    //pseudo-code
    public static T Max<T>(T x, T y, Func<T, T, int> cmp)
    {
        return (cmp(x, y) > 0) ? x : y;
    }

    public static T Max<T>(T x, T y) where T: IComparable<T>
    {
        return Max(x, y, (a, b) => { return a.CompareTo(b); });
    }

    public static T Max<T>(T x, T y) where T: IComparable
    {
        return Max(x, y, (a, b) => { return a.CompareTo(b); });
    }
```

But, this is neither possible, because overload resolution doesn't takes into account Generics Constraints....

Then, I'll leave out `IComparable` consciously. I'm just going to worry about `IComparable<T>`

```
    public static T Max<T>(T x, T y, Func<T, T, int> cmp)
    {
        return (cmp(x, y) > 0) ? x : y;
    }

    public static T Max<T>(T x, T y) where T: IComparable<T>
    {
        return Max(x, y, (a, b) => { return a.CompareTo(b); });
    }
```

Comment: That's a good point about lack of compile-time type safety. But if you're going to make a claim about run-time cost, I'd really like to see you back it up with some numbers. I haven't tested it either, but I'd think passing a function would cause some performance penalty too.

Comment: @Carl Walsh.
My point is not about type safety, but about Generic Programming. 

Comparer<T>.Default uses Reflection. It is well known that Reflection has a high cost in run-time, I think it is not necessary to prove it here.
Especially if we compare Reflection with something that can be resolved at compile time, there is a huge difference in performance.
Anyway, In a few days, I'll make an update with some numbers.

Comment: @Carl Walsh.
Regarding passing a function as a parameter, first, the function that receives CMP as a parameter is necessary to compare a pair of elements with an *equivalence* relation. The second function compares two elements using *equality*.
Second, regarding to the penalty of passing a function as a parameter, any reasonable compiler can do inlining of the CMP, so that the final code would be the same as if we had written A.CompareTo(b) by hand.

Comment: @FernandoPelliccioni your claim isn't entirely right. You should have taken a look at the source code for DefaultComparer. It is very smart! It will cache the default comparer in a static volatile variable of Comparer<T>. So you pay the price only once and after that it will be faster than (or as fast as) a typecast to IComparable<T>. Using DefaultComparer will make the function MORE "generic" than the "more academic" Comparable<T> solution. And you should not fear runtime exceptions. Compile time checking is no substitute for unit testing. Unit test your code and use the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

This is a little too late, but why not use dynamic types and delegates as an alternative to IComparable?  This way you get compile-type safety in most cases and will only get a runtime error when the types supplied both do not support the operator < and you fail to provide the default comparer as an argument.

```
public static T Max<T>(T first, T second, Func<T,T,bool> f = null)
{
    Func<dynamic,dynamic,bool> is_left_smaller = (x, y) => x < y ? true : false;

    var compare = f ?? new Func<T, T, bool>((x, y) => is_left_smaller(x, y));

    return compare(first, second) ? second : first; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

.NET 7 introduces a new feature - generic math (read more [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-7-generic-math/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11#generic-math-support)) which is based on addition of [`static abstract` interface methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/static-virtual-interface-members#static-abstract-interface-methods). This feature introduces a lot of interfaces which allow to generically abstract over number types and/or math operations, which allows to rewrite the function in question as:

```cs
public T Max<T>(T v1, T v2) where T: IComparisonOperators<T, T, bool> => v1 > v2 ? v1 : v2;
```

Note that for build-in number types usually you don't need to define your own `Max` because it is already defined on the [`INumber<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.inumber-1?view=net-7.0) interface:

```cs
public interface INumber<TSelf> : 
// ... other interfaces,
System.Numerics.IComparisonOperators<TSelf,TSelf,bool>
// ... other interfaces
 where TSelf : INumber<TSelf>
```

Answer (score 1):

*The solution I present on this answer would have worked (I actually did something like this) at the time the question was asked. I'm surprised no answer presents this alternative, thus I'll present it.*

You can (and could have used back then) `Linq.Expressions` (Which was added in .NET 3.5, in 2007, making it a valid answer at the time of the question).

For starters:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

// ...

public T Max<T>(T v1, T v2)
{
    var expression = Expression.GreaterThan
        (
            Expression.Constant(v1),
            Expression.Constant(v2)
        );
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(expression).Compile()() ? v1 : v2);
}
```

*That has no need of `dynamic`, or `Comparison<T>`/`IComparer<T>`.*

I believe that having a way to specify a custom comparison is better, but that is not what we are doing here. And of course, any type for which the presented solution works, `Comparer<T>.Default` would work. However, using `Linq.Expressions` would allow you implement **any arithmetic operations**. *Take this as illustration of that approach.*

There is, of course, overhead. Let us have a version that does compile to a function with parameters, we can think later about how to cache it:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

// ...

public T Max<T>(T v1, T v2)
{
    var a = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "a");
    var b = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "b");
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, bool>>
    (
        Expression.GreaterThan(a, b),
        new[]{a, b}
    );
    return ((Func<T, T, bool>)lambda.Compile())(v1, v2) ? v1 : v2;
}
```

Alright, to cache it, let us start with the generic class approach, which is easier to write:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class GenericMath<T>
{
    private static Func<T, T, bool>? _greaterThan;
    
    public static Func<T, T, bool> GetGreaterThan()
    {
        if (_greaterThan == null)
        {
            var a = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "a");
            var b = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "b");
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, bool>>
            (
                Expression.GreaterThan(a, b),
                new[]{a, b}
            );
            _greaterThan = (Func<T, T, bool>)lambda.Compile();
        }
        
        return _greaterThan;
    }

    public static T Max(T v1, T v2)
    {
        return GetGreaterThan()(v1, v2) ? v1 : v2;
    }
}
```

Of course, statics on generics has drawbacks (there is a performance cost, plus the memory is never released). We can start our way to a better solution by using a dictionary cache instead:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class GenericMath
{
    private readonly static Dictionary<Type, Delegate> _gtCache = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();
    
    public static Func<T, T, bool> GetGreaterThan<T>()
    {
        if (!_gtCache.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var @delegate) || @delegate == null)
        {
            var a = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "a");
            var b = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "b");
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, bool>> 
            (
                Expression.GreaterThan(a, b),
                new[]{a, b}
            );
            @delegate = lambda.Compile();
            _addCache[typeof(T)] = @delegate;
        }
        
        return (Func<T, T, bool>)@delegate;
    }

    public static T Max<T>(T v1, T v2)
    {
        return GetGreaterThan<T>()(v1, v2) ? v1 : v2;
    }
}
```

Ok, I hear you, I have introduced a new problem: that solution is not thread-safe.

We could use `ConcurrentDictionary` (added in .NET 4.0, which -if I'm not mistaken- was on beta at the time of the question), but we would not be releasing memory anyway. Instead, we can make a custom class for this use:

```
public sealed class TypeCacheDict<TValue>
{
    private const int Capacity = 256;
    private readonly Entry[] _entries;

    public TypeCacheDict()
    {
        _entries = new Entry[Capacity];
    }

    public TValue this[Type key]
    {
        get
        {
            if (TryGetValue(key, out var value))
            {
                return value;
            }

            throw new KeyNotFoundException();
        }
        set => Add(key, value);
    }

    public void Add(Type key, TValue value)
    {
        if (key == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
        }

        var hash = key.GetHashCode();
        var index = hash & (_entries.Length - 1);
        var entry = _entries[index];
        Thread.MemoryBarrier();
        if (entry?.Hash != hash || !entry.Key.Equals(key))
        {
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref _entries[index], new Entry(hash, key, value));
        }
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(Type key, out TValue value)
    {
        if (key == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
        }

        var hash = key.GetHashCode();
        var index = hash & (_entries.Length - 1);
        var entry = _entries[index];
        Thread.MemoryBarrier();
        if (entry?.Hash == hash && entry.Key.Equals(key))
        {
            value = entry.Value;
            return value != null;
        }

        value = default;
        return false;
    }

    private sealed class Entry
    {
        internal readonly int Hash;
        internal readonly Type Key;
        internal readonly TValue Value;

        internal Entry(int hash, Type key, TValue value)
        {
            Hash = hash;
            Key = key;
            Value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This `TypeCacheDict` is thread-safe. First of all `Entry` is immutable. We don't need to worry about shared access to it. Plus, it a reference type, so replacing it is an atomic operation. We are using `Thread.MemoryBarrier` and `Interlocked.Exchange` o mimic `Volatile.Read` and `Volatile.Write` because `Volatile` was not available (and `Thread.Volatile*` lacks generic overload, and I would rather not instroduce extra casts).

With this new type we can now write:

```
private readonly static TypeCacheDict<Delegate> _gtCache = new TypeCacheDict<Delegate>();
```

The rest of the code could be left unchanged. Although there is room for improvement: `TryGetOrAdd`:

```
    public TValue TryGetOrAdd(Type key, Func<TValue> valueFactory)
    {
        if (key == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
        }
        
        if (valueFactory == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(valueFactory));
        }

        var hash = key.GetHashCode();
        var index = hash & (_entries.Length - 1);
        var entry = _entries[index];
        Thread.MemoryBarrier();
        if (entry?.Hash == hash && entry.Key.Equals(key))
        {
            return entry.Value;
        }
        
        var value = valueFactory();
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref _entries[index], new Entry(hash, key, value));
        return value;
    }
```

Which allows us to write:

```
    public static Func<T, T, bool> GetGreaterThan<T>()
    {
        return (Func<T, T, bool>)_gtCache.TryGetOrAdd
        (
            typeof(T),
            ()=>
            {
                var a = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "a");
                var b = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "b");
                var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, bool>>(Expression.GreaterThan(a, b), new[]{a, b});
                return lambda.Compile();
            }
        );
    }
```

Of course, this is how you use it:

```
Console.WriteLine(GenericMath.Max<int>(90, 100)); // 100
```

---

To demostrate, the power of this approach, this is `Add`:

```
    private readonly static TypeCacheDict<Delegate> _addCache = new TypeCacheDict<Delegate>();
    
    public static Func<T, T, T> GetAdd<T>()
    {
        return (Func<T, T, T>)_addCache.TryGetOrAdd
        (
            typeof(T),
            ()=>
            {
                var a = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "a");
                var b = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "b");
                var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, T>>(Expression.Add(a,b), new[]{a, b});
                return lambda.Compile();
            }
        );
    }

    public static T Add<T>(T v1, T v2)
    {
        return GetAdd<T>()(v1, v2);
    }
```

And this is how you use it:

```
Console.WriteLine(GenericMath.Add<int>(90, 100)); // 190
```

Answer (score 0):

From memory, T also needs to be `IComparable` (add that to the `where`), and then you use `v1.CompareTo(v2) > 0` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Necromancing.
You can have a Max/Min function on an arbitrary number of parameters:

```
public static T Min<T>(params T[] source) 
    where T: struct, IComparable<T>
{
    if (source == null) 
        throw new System.ArgumentNullException("source");

    T value = default(T);
    bool hasValue = false;
    foreach (T x in source)
    {
        if (hasValue)
        {
            // if (x < value) // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1?view=netcore-3.1
            // Less than zero This object precedes the object specified by the CompareTo method in the sort order.
            // Zero This current instance occurs in the same position in the sort order as the object specified by the CompareTo method argument.
            // Greater than zero
            if (x.CompareTo(value) < 0)
                value = x;
        }
        else
        {
            value = x;
            hasValue = true;
        }
    }

    if (hasValue) 
        return value;

    throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Sequence contains no elements");
}


public static T Max<T>(params T[] source) 
    where T : struct, IComparable<T>
{
    if (source == null) 
        throw new System.ArgumentNullException("source");

    T value = default(T);
    bool hasValue = false;
    foreach (T x in source)
    {
        if (hasValue)
        {
            // if (x > value) // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1?view=netcore-3.1
            // Less than zero This object precedes the object specified by the CompareTo method in the sort order.
            // Zero This current instance occurs in the same position in the sort order as the object specified by the CompareTo method argument.
            // Greater than zero
            if (x.CompareTo(value) > 0)
                value = x;
        }
        else
        {
            value = x;
            hasValue = true;
        }
    }

    if (hasValue) 
        return value;

    throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Sequence contains no elements");
}
```